# Добавление объекта в массив

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть массив вида

```
[File, File, File]
0:File
1:File
2:File
```

Как добавить объект с заданным ключ-значением ? Пробую так

```
var obj = {};
obj[image_id] = file;
images.push(obj);
```

Получаю

```
[Object]
0:Object
 86:File
```

Если так

```
images[image_id] = file;
```

Получаю

```
[86: File]
 86:File
```

Comment: а какой результат-то ожидается?

Comment: Массив объектов

Comment: ну так вы его и получаете = причем в обоих ваших примерах. Что в их результатах не нравится?

Comment: Изначально было так

`[File, File, File]
0:File
1:File
2:File`

Мне нужно было иметь возможность добавлять объекты в массив + менять уже существующие элементы в массиве, но в итоге я получал это

`[86: File]
 86:File`

Вместо

`[File]
 86:File`

В итоге, к примеру если прогнать такой массив через each, получал кол-во элементов от 0 до 86 :)

Comment: так у вас первый вариант делает как раз то, что вы хотите, зачем даже второй было придумывать?

Comment: Первый отдает это

`[Object]
0:Object
 86:File`

Comment: Так правильно, если вы добавляете в пустой массив объект он именно это и должен отдавать. Сейчас в вопрос **абсолютно** непонятно какой код у вас есть, как вы его используете и **почему** не подходят указанные в вопросе варианты. Вам стоит его отредактировать.

Comment: Изначально планировалось что объект будет вида `86:File` Потом я добавил еще свойства. В итоге отказался от первонального решения, и остановился на `images.push({key: id, value: file});` Т.к. свойств может быть несколько.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй так: 
данный код вставляет значение 2 между 1 и 3

```
var my_array = [0,1,3,4];
var start_index = 1;
var number_of_elements_to_remove = 0;
my_array.splice(start_index, number_of_elements_to_remove, 2);
console.log(my_array);  // [1,2,3,4];
```

Comment: вроде он другое спрашивал

Comment: @stas.t, `splice` - далеко не простой способ

Comment: согласен, что то я напортачил. по невнимательности не понял что требуется

Comment: @Grundy , прошу прошения если из-за своей неопытности ввёл кого то в заблуждение. правда думал что мой код поможет разобраться в вопросе человеку.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
var filesArr = ['file.jpg', 'secfile.jpg', 'elsefile.jpg'];

filesArr.forEach(function(element) {
  var obj = {};
  obj['image_id'] = element;
  arr.push(obj);
});


document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Вариант через map

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var arr = [];
  var filesArr = ['file.jpg', 'secfile.jpg', 'elsefile.jpg'];

  arr = filesArr.map(function(el) {
    return {
      image_id: el
    };
  });

  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);

}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: JSON.stringify не подходит

Comment: @Гость stringify - это просто визуализация того, что массив с объектами сформирован. Добавление объектов в массив в внутри метода forEach.

Comment: я сделал так

`var images = [];
images.push({key: id, value: file});`

Comment: @Jean-Claude, почему не `map`?

Comment: Без понятия, если честно. А какие отличия, в скорости выполнения ?

Comment: @Grundy дописал второй вариант. Изначально хотел через jquery each, потом подумал проще без него и вспомнил про foreach))

Comment: @Гость, если у вас меньше, скажем, 1к элементов, то про разницу в скорости можно забыть.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял то код может быть таким:

```
<script>
    var arr = new Array("File", "File", "File");

    arr[3] = new Object();

    arr[3]["mykey"] = "MyFile";

    alert(arr[3]["mykey"]); // выведет MyFile   
    alert(arr[3].mykey); // то же самое
</script>
```